# sort() is working fine but using it to display the complete sort data frame gives different output and not the sorted output

Tags: r

I want to sort the data frame by the contents of column.
On using sort() function but not getting a sorted data frame

I have a data frame with column like name, age, gender.
I want to sort the data frame according to age

I tried sort(data_info$Age) which gave correct output :

```r
> my_sort <- sort(data_info$Age)
 [1] 19 19 19 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 21 23
Levels: 19 20 21 23
```

now want to sort complete data frame according to age, so used :

```
> group_info_df[my_sort,]
```

I expect a sorted data frame but the output was

```
         Gender Age Favorite_Food Day_of_birth
Marcos     Male  23         Pizza           24        
Marcos.1   Male  23         Pizza           24        
Marcos.2   Male  23         Pizza           24        
Sahil      Male  20          Dosa           17         
Sahil.1    Male  20          Dosa           17         
Sahil.2    Male  20          Dosa           17         
Sahil.3    Male  20          Dosa           17         
Sahil.4    Male  20          Dosa           17
```

It displayed the same row many times instead of showing all other rows.
what's the error or how to resolve this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to use `order` instead of `sort` as `sort` returns the sorted values, but it can also get the index if we use `index.return = TRUE`.  Then, it would return a `list` with names 'x' and 'ix' for the sorted values and the corresponding index.  By looking at the data, the column is `factor`.  We can convert it to `numeric` and then `order` to order the rows of the dataset

```
new_df <- group_info_df[order(as.numeric(as.character(data_info$Age))),,
          drop = FALSE]

row.names(new_df) <- NULL
```

Comment: Ok thanks. So, sort() does not have the functionality, we have to use order()

Comment: @sahilkharya  As I mentioned in the post, you can uses `sort(..., index.return = TRUE)`